# apply css rule to everything apart from one tag

Tags: html, css

I want to apply a css rule to everything (`* { color: red; }`).

But, how can I do this without the need for Javascript or applying a class to everything I want it to be applied to?

Something like:

```
*:not-type(div) {
    color: red;
}
```

And the document would be:

```
<span>this is red</span>
<span>this is red</span>
<div>this is not red</div>
```

Comment: why not just apply a class to the thing you don't want to be red and style that to override it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
:not(div){
      color: red;
    }
```

Comment: `:not(div)` will match the body element. Then the div element inherits the red color from that.

Comment: Yes it works with `p` but as you can see in the JsFiddle, it doen'st work with `div`

Comment: It works with the `p` because the w3schools example is broken or at least misleading, by giving a separate explicit rule for `p`, which sort of defeats the whole idea of using `:not(p)`.

Comment: it works with the div (change p to div) in the w3schools.   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
    color: #0000ff;
}

:not(div) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a heading</h1>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

<div>This is some text in a div element.</div>

<a href="http://www.w3schools.com" target="_blank">Link to W3Schools!</a>

</body>
</html>

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
*{
color: red;
}

div{
color: blue;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't allow leaving `div` with its default or inherited color, which `:not` does.

Answer (score 2):

To select everything except div elements you would write:

```
:not(div) {
    color: red;
}
```

Caveat: while this rule correctly selects all elements except div, it does not prevent a div from *inheriting* red color from its parent which is the default behavior.

Comment: What if you had `<section><div>...</div><p>...</p></section>`? Excluding the body element only works for very simple documents.